# Value changed once reflected everywhere in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
sz = input('Enter the size of the board: ')
board = [[0 for j in xrange(sz)] for i in xrange(sz)]

for row in range(sz):
    for col in range(sz):
        board[row][col] = input()

pqval = 1
steps = 2
start_state = sz , board , pqval ,steps

t=1
for row in range(sz):
    for col in range(sz):
        board[row][col] = t
        t=t+1
board[sz-1][sz-1] = 0
end_state = sz, board , pqval ,steps

print "Here is the starting position: "
print start_state

print "Here is the ending position: "
print end_state
```

I fail to understand why the change also takes place in start_state's board attribute even though the it was constructed earlier. I am definitely doing something stupid. New to python and coming from C/C++ background this behavior seems strange.

What is the work around if I want tuples having all the 4 values and wish to change attributes of one tuple without this being replicated everywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, stack snippets only work for JavaScript(+HTML+CSS) at this point; just use a regular code block for Python. (I've edited this one for you.)

Comment: [This article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is one of the best explanations of how names actually work in Python that I know of.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon: Agreed. A couple of times, I wrote a blog post to explain something simple but hard to explain, only to find that Ned Batchelder had written a simpler and better explanation the previous week. The last time this came up, I was smart enough to check first, and of course Ned had written it so much better than I possibly could that I just pointed people there and saved my time. Thanks for reminding me; that belong in my bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, assignment is very different from C++; in fact, the very notion of a variable is different.

- In C++, a variable is a memory address where the value is stored, together with a type. You can take a reference or even a pointer of a variable. Assignment means copying a value from one variable to another.*
- In Python, a value takes care of its own storage and type; a variable is just a name for a value. One value can have any number of names.**

<sub>* … usually; you can override it to mean whatever you want.</sub>

<sub>** Well, any positive number. Once it has no names, it will get cleaned up by the garbage collector.</sub>

---

You probably know this in simple cases:

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0]
0
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> b[0]
1
```

But it's true in *every* case. So, when you do this:

```
start_state = sz , board , pqval ,steps
```

… that just means `start_state[1]` becomes another name for the same `board` object. The fact that `start_state[1]` is a "complex target" rather than a plain variable doesn't matter; the fact that you created it indirectly by assigning to `start_state` rather than assigning directly to `start_state[1]` doesn't matter; it's still a name.

Of course the same is true for `sz`, `pqval`, and `steps`, but you never mutate those values— because you *can't*; strings and numbers can't be mutated.

Reassigning `pqval` doesn't turn `1` into a different number;* it just makes `pqval` a name for a different number, while leaving `start_state[2]` still a name for the original one. In the same way, reassigning `board` would also not affect `start_state[1]`. It's only mutating `board` in-place that does this.

<sub>* If you could do that, that would be a hell of a superpower, but any use of it would probably break the universe…</sub>

This can get a little tricky when you use operators like `+=`, especially if you're used to C++. In C++, `+=` always means mutating a variable, whether or not it means mutating a value; when you can't mutate a variable, `+=` just doesn't work. In Python, there's no such thing as "mutating a variable"; it always mean *reassigning* a variable, whether or not it means mutating a value; when you can't mutate a value, `+=` just makes a new value to reassign to.

---

If you want to make a copy, you have to do it explicitly. For example, any of these would work:

```
start_state = sz, board[:], pqval, steps
start_state = sz, copy.copy(board), pqval, steps
start_state = copy.deepcopy((sz, board, pqval, steps))
```

---

Or, alternatively, you could make `board` work the same way as those other objects—never mutate it, only reassign it to new lists. For example, instead of this:

```
    board[row][col] = t
```

… you could do:

```
    board = [[val if i, j != row, col else t for j, val in enumerate(row)]
             for i, row in enumerate(board)]
```

Of course that's a little silly, but often you can rewrite a loop as a list comprehension that generates a new list, and that's *not* silly. For example:

```
board = [[i*sz+j for j in range(sz)] for i in range(sz)]
```

Comment: Is this always true ?
Because when I try following in ipython shell: t=1;p=(1,t);t++;
print p. It shows (1,1) instead of (1,2)

Comment: @AnuragSharma: Yes, it's always true.

Comment: `t++` is not valid Python, but if you mean `t+=1`, then the difference is that `t` refers to an immutable `int` object, so that `t+=1` makes the *name* `t` refer to a new value, as opposed to changing the `int` object that `t` refers to.

Comment: @AnuragSharma: chepner is 100% right. But I find it easier to think of it this way: `p[1]` isn't a reference to `t`, it's a reference to _the same value that `t` is a reference to_. So, making `t` into a reference to something else doesn't affect `p[1]` at all. I've tried to edit the answer to explain this more clearly.